# If you get up vs If you'll get up

Tags: subjunctives

I'm reading *The Great Gatsby by F.Scott Fitzgerald* and there's one part of the book where *Jordan Baker* goes to sleep and says:

> 'Good-night' she said softly. 'Wake me at eight, won't you?'
>
> If you'll get up
>
> I will. Good-night, Mr Carraway. See you anon.

What does `If you will` mean in this context?

Could be the sentence  written as `If you get up`?

Comment: You can read "If you'll get up" as "(I'll do that) if you'll get up". I believe that using *will* (in *If you'll getup*) sounds better because the getting up is a consequence of being waken up.

Comment: @DamkerngT.: I wonder if we can reconstruct it as "If you **will** (be able to) get up when I **try** to wake you tomorrow, then I **will** indeed be successful in waking you."

Comment: @CopperKettle Not quite, I think. I think it's more like, "I'll wake you if you will get up if (when) I wake you."

Comment: @DamkerngT. -  Lewis Carroll would've liked the question.

Comment: I found this: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77790/what-does-if-you-will-mean could be the sentence written as "If you want to get up"?

Comment: Do what you will. Sit here if you will. The Free Dictionary uses "will" as a verb to mean to desire or wish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> - If you get up.
> - If you'll get up.

We don't usually see the auxiliary verb *will* in the *if*-clauses of conditionals. One time that we do see it is when *will* has the meaning of *agree to* or *be willing to*. The first example is just a normal conditional where we use the present simple in the *if*-clause, although we're talking about the future. In the Original Poster's example, *"if you **'ll** get up"* has the meaning: *"if you're willing to get up"*. The version without *will* is perfectly grammatical, but doesn't have this extra meaning.

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 5):

I am willing to try to rouse you tomorrow morning (only) if you actually wake up when I do (and not say you want to stay asleep, for example).

Call me tonight.
--If you'll answer.

The implication of the reply is that often calls are sent to voice-mail, say.